# check if package name belongs to a CRAN archived package

Tags: r, cran

How can one check of a package has been archived from CRAN.  One can check if a package is a CRAN package like so:

```
"ggplot2" %in% available.packages()[,1]
## [1] TRUE
```

But a package like **helpr** shows false with the same code.  How could I check if a name is archived?

```
"helpr" %in% available.packages()[,1]
## [1] FALSE
```

I could scrape the archive like this:

```
archs <- XML::readHTMLTable(readLines("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/"), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

gsub("/$", "", na.omit(archs[[1]][, "Name"]))
```

but I assume there is a built in base way to to do this as using an archived package name will throw a warning in a CRAN check.

Comment: _I assume there is a built in base way_: why?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel if you use helpr as a package name and run r cmd check -as.cran a warning is thrown.  The check must be using something or I am assuming because I don't know what r cmd is doing.

Comment: All the code for that is in the `tools` package (or maybe `utils`, I always mix that up), so did you look?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks Yeah I thought so too (at least on the **utils**) and so looked at the **utils** but did not see what I believe gives that.  Maybe I need to understand more how R CDM check`  works.  I'll look through **tools** there may be something in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R CMD check` basically calls `tools:::.check_packages`. The functionality you're looking for is in `tools:::.check_package_CRAN_incoming`, and `tools:::CRAN_archive_db`.

**Edit** *(by Tyler Rinker)*  Using Josh's answer the following code gives me what I'm after though less well succint than @hrbrmstr's:

```
get_archived <- function(cran = getOption("repos")){
    if (is.null(cran)) cran <- "http://cran.rstudio.com/"
    con <- gzcon(url(sprintf("%s/%s", cran, "src/contrib/Meta/archive.rds"), open = "rb"))
    on.exit(close(con))
    x <- readRDS(con)
    names(x)
}


check_archived <- function(package){
    tolower(package) %in% tolower(get_archived())
}

check_archived("ggplot2")
check_archived("helpr")
check_archived("foo")

## > check_archived("ggplot2")
## [1] TRUE
## > check_archived("helpr")
## [1] TRUE
## > check_archived("foo")
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: I added code based on your response.  If it doesn't fit feel free to roll back.

Comment: This doesn't seem to return the correct result for package `mm`. `check_archived("mm")` returns `FALSE`, but `R CMD check --as-cran` gives two messages: `Conflicting package names (submitted: mm, existing: MM [https://CRAN.R-project.org])` and `Conflicting package names (submitted: mm, existing: MM [CRAN archive])`

Comment: ohhh... it's case sensitive `check_archived("MM")` returns `TRUE`

Comment: @Joshua I made an edit which reflects CRAN policy (that case doesn't matter e.g. if MM exists, then mm is not allowed)

Comment: @stevec thanks! I knew the policy, but didn't account for it in the answer. Thank you for fixing!

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, rolling your own `CRAN_archive_db` would be something like:

```
download.file("https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Meta/archive.rds",
              "archive.rds")
archive <- readRDS("archive.rds")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the somewhat-recently-released package `available` by the [ROpenSciLabs](https://github.com/ropenscilabs) is designed for this (and much more):

[github.com/ropenscilabs/available](https://github.com/ropenscilabs/available)

Its readme (as of now) lists:

- Checks for validity
- Checks not already available on GitHub, CRAN and Bioconductor
- Searches Urban Dictionary, Wiktionary and Wikipedia for unintended meanings
- Can suggest possible names based on text in the package title or description.